Firmware of QLogic NetXtreme II BCM57840 4x10GbE
I have a 10G card which has two 10G ports, I plugged that into the PCI slot, only one port works and the second port doesn't work for some reason, it also reports that it has 4x10GbE which I believe is due to the wrong firmware. Can someone tell me how can I update the firmware on it ? I have only CentOS and FreeBSD, the iLo shows the name of this card as Adapter 1 - QLogic 577xx/578xx 10 Gigabit Ethernet (BCM57840) and the firmware version is not visible which again I believe is due to wrong firmware burnt on it.
Can someone share the link of the latest firmware for this card and also with the instructions on how to get it burnt with the latest firmware on CentOS or FreeBSD.

are you sure you are working on a business environment?

I didn't understand you :(

welcome to serverfault.com where you can ask business related question or issue in here. please describe the business problem you are working on and enough information to reproduce. 8f the HW seems to be broken replace it immediately as best practices
